# Conditional filter expression in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

So I have two filtering objects. One is a drop down list, which chooses the group of users to look at. Next is the user search box. I would like to use this to filter the results further so that you can search for a user **in the chosen group**.
I have tested the group filter and it works on it's own (without the inclusion of the searchbox).

Now, the problem I face is the default view. What I want to **also** be able to do is choose a group without putting in a user, giving me the complete list of users in that group. Then if I want to filter it down more I would use the searchbox.

Currently I have to use the searchbox in order to have any results show. I suspect it's the default value I have set for the searchbox control parameter, but I am unsure how to fix it (I have tried putting the wildcard in but then it doesn't filter by group anymore)

Here is the filter expression:

```
FilterExpression="(([Field1] = {0}) AND ([Field2] LIKE '%{1}%'))"
```

And here are the parameters:

```
    <FilterParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DDL" Name="Field1" 
                          PropertyName="SelectedValue" 
                          Type="Int32" />
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="SearchBox" Name="Field2"  
                          Type="String" />
    </FilterParameters>

<SelectParameters>
     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DDL" Name="Field1" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />  
     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="SearchBox" Name="Field2" Type="String" DefaultValue="" />  
</SelectParameters>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put default value as "" in filter parameter for search box.

```
<FilterParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DDL" Name="GroupId" 
                      PropertyName="SelectedValue" 
                      Type="Int32" />
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="SearchBox" Name="UserName"  
                      Type="String" DefaultValue=""/>
</FilterParameters>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried it but there is no change - I still have to put something in the search box to obtain any results.

Comment: Ah - solved it! I set DefaultValue="ALL" on BOTH the searchbox controlparameters! (Whereas before I only had one with the default value)
Thanks heaps! I needed this inclusion for it to work :)

Comment: Gah, sorry - I meant DefaultValue="%". My head isn't here today! xD